# React-native flex height

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I have 3 components and I am trying to set their heights (header, body, footer) but when it renders, each component has just the height of one line of text it contains.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Header from './Header';
import Body from './Body';
import Footer from './Footer';
import * as globalStyles from '../styles/global';


const HomeScreen = () => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Header style={{ flex: 1 }} title={'MyTitle'}>
      <Text>Component</Text>
    </Header>
    <Body style={{ flex: 3 }}>
      <Text>my body</Text>
    </Body>
    <Footer style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text>my footer</Text>
    </Footer>
  </View>
);

export default HomeScreen;
```

App

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import HomeScreen from './components/HomeScreen';
import createStore from './createStore';

const store = createStore();

export default () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <HomeScreen />
  </Provider>
);
```

Header

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as globalStyles from '../styles/global';

const Header = ({ children, title }) => (
  <View>
    <Text style={globalStyles.COMMON_STYLES.text}>
      {children}
      {title}
      {title}
    </Text>
  </View>
);

Header.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    paddingTop: 20
  }
});
export default Header;
```

Footer

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as globalStyles from '../styles/global';

const Footer = ({ children }) => (
  <View>
    <Text style={globalStyles.COMMON_STYLES.text}>
      {children}
    </Text>
  </View>
);

Footer.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    marginTop: 20,
    flex: 1,
  }
});
export default Footer;
```

Body

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as globalStyles from '../styles/global';

const Body = ({ children, title }) => (
  <View>
    <Text style={globalStyles.COMMON_STYLES.text}>
      {children}
      {title}
      {title}
    </Text>
  </View>
);

Body.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    marginTop: 20,
    flex: 1,
  }
});
export default Body;
```

global styles

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export const BG_COLOR = '#343336';
export const BAR_COLOR = '#4e4d52';
export const TEXT_COLOR = '#e5dbda';
export const HEADER_TEXT_COLOR = '#fff';
export const MUTED_COLOR = '#8e8786';
export const LINK_COLOR = '#48e9d9';
export const ACCENT_COLORS = ['#d31d65', '#751c53', '#c248c0', '#7d6e8b', '#bbc6f7'];

export const COMMON_STYLES = StyleSheet.create({
  pageContainer: {
    backgroundColor: BG_COLOR,
    marginTop: 0,
    paddingTop: 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 10
  },
  text: {
    color: TEXT_COLOR,
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue'
  }
});
```

My understanding is that the Body should be 3 x the height of header or footer.

React-native:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.41.2
```

Comment: This code alone works fine as you expect. Try sharing the entire code of that screen. Btw what version of RN are you using?

Comment: I've added more code - although there are more styles there - I can't see how it would interfere with the height.

Comment: What I was looking for was the place where you use the HomeScreen, Is it wrapped in some other container, whether flex is defined for those wrapping containers if any?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I don't thinks so. See my updated answer.

Comment: Flex should be given to your root containers of the header, body and footer components. Header, Footer and Body are custom components, the style props won't be applicable to them, the style you applied just get passed as a prop to child.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**
Flex should be given to your root containers of the header, body and footer components. Header, Footer and Body are custom components, the style props won't be applicable to them, the style you applied just get passed as a **prop**

```
const Footer = ({ children }) => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>  // root container of footer
    <Text style={globalStyles.COMMON_STYLES.text}>
      {children}
    </Text>
  </View>
);

const Body = ({ children, title }) => (
   <View style={{ flex: 3 }}>
    <Text style={globalStyles.COMMON_STYLES.text}>
      {children}
      {title}
      {title}
    </Text>
   </View>
);

const Header = ({ children, title }) => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}> // root container of header
    <Text style={globalStyles.COMMON_STYLES.text}>
      {children}
      {title}
      {title}
    </Text>
  </View>
);
```

Hope its working for you

Comment: Ok. Sorry - I need a bit clarification. Flex should be given to root components. Does you mean: 
  <Provider store={store}>
    <HomeScreen style={{ flex: 1 }} />
  </Provider>
);
? Also I'm not sure I understand your last sentence.

Comment: By root container of Header/Footer/Body I meant to give flex to the outermost container of the component that ie View as shown in my answer. Styleprops can only be given directly to native components. I ll edit my answer to add comments in code

Comment: HomeScreen is not a native component so no need to give it flex directly. So when you apply style={{ flex: 1}} to it, it will be considered as a prop and within the HomeScreen you will get an object { flex: 1 } when you console this.props.style. Just like you passed title to Header component. Hope this clears your doubt

Comment: +1 for specifying custom components won't have styles set for it by default, needs to code for taking use of style, something like `<Header style={props.style} />` -- `Header, Footer and Body are custom components, the style props won't be applicable to them`